# Using JWrapper to build java application

Tags: java, installation, jwrapper

Need some inputs on below points. Thanks in advance.

We have deployed our project using JWrapper in Mac version.

For a latest upgrade installation, I have been trying to just replace the updated jars files (from other Mac OS) to check for a delta update.

The application stop running and gives exception something like ”Encrypted data integrity check failed”.

What I understand with this is there is a checksum added for each version of the package done by JWrapper.

In that case how I can only replace a jar (in client location) to support a delta update.

Please let me know if you need any other info.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JWCrypt then you will need to use the JWrapper update mechanism, its not possible to replace just one jar in the installation since the jar is encrypted.